# Custom grid view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-gridview

This is my code:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context ctx;
String [] items ={"72","58","67","77","90"} ; //Can be images or video or any other content
String [] stuff = {"bus to town ","Bus to north","Bus to west","Bus to east","Bus out"};
public CustomGridAdapter(Context c) {
    ctx = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(ctx);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(items[position]));
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(stuff[position]));
    return tv;
}
```

}

Need help trying to figure out how to display tv2 below tv .
Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do not you create a layout xml and inflate these xml in method getView(....)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a vertical LinearLayout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(ctx);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(items[position]));
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(stuff[position]));
    layout.addView(tv);
    layout.addView(tv2);
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);, the this doesnt work any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: The constructor LinearLayout(CustomGridAdapter) is undefined thtas what it says

Comment: I fixed the typo, replace this with ctx